# python-oauth package currupt

Tags: python, linux, r

I am working with Ubuntu linux Lucid Lynx running on the Oracle VirtualBox. WhenI I'm trying to get the R package (r-base) or the python matplotlib package with

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

im getting this error:

> dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 30898
>   package 'python-oauth': missing version

Does anyone know the solution for this, because I can't find answers on google though.
I already tried to remove the python-oauth package, but then I get the same error message.
Also updating and installing it with force won't help.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

Then try again

If that doesn't work, try

```
apt-get install r-base --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no succes. Still the same error. More suggestions?